# getting error while using AliasToBeanResultTransformer

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

I am using the below AliasToBeanResultTransformer but it is throwing exception with the explnation that an invalid column name  , below is my code please advise how to overcome from this

```
Session session = ((HibernateSessionImpl) this.session).getSession();

String Sql = ""
                + "SELECT a_system, "
                + "       c_id, "               //column name written in table in DB
                + "       t_id, "               //column name written in table in DB
                + "       l_id "                //column name written in table in DB  
                + "FROM   ilogger ";            //column name written in table in DB


          List<IOAPublishingRulesDetails> uy = (List<IOAPublishingRulesDetails>) session
            .createSQLQuery(Sql)
            .addScalar("asystem", Hibernate.STRING) //column namew riiten in this way in pojo
            .addScalar("cid", Hibernate.STRING) //column namew riiten in this way in pojo
            .addScalar("tId", Hibernate.LONG)//column namew riiten in this way in pojo
            .addScalar("lid", Hibernate.STRING)//column namew riiten in this way in pojo
            .setResultTransformer(
              new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(IOAPublishingRulesDetails.class)).list();

          System.out.println(uy.size());
```

FOLKS PLEASE ADVISE ANY HELP WOULD BE MUCH APPRECIATED.thanks IN ADVANCE

below is the stack trace of the exception

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
```

Comment: The error message says it all. One of the column names at least is not correct. Note that, you shouldn't use SQL but HQL for such a simple query, and you should also not cast the session to HibernateSessionImpl. The standard Session interface has everything you need to execute queries.

Comment: Please show IOAPublishingRulesDetails class with its fields, setters and getters.